# Observable subscription twice

Tags: angular, observable

I am using angular 4 with observable.

Actually shared data between components using subject and observables.

Here is my function.

```
getNewSearchResults(): Observable<any> {
    return this._searchResultOne.asObservable();
  }
```

I just subscribe the function using this

```
this.searchService.getNewSearchResults().subscribe(res=>{
            console.log("res",res);
 })
```

same time result is returned twice.why?

How can i do it.

Please advice me,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the subscription in `ngOnInit()` method and unsubscribe the observable in `ngOnDestroy()` method. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Its works.But i have one doubt.Its worked when directly added ngOnInit(). At the same time i added another function.the function inside subscribe route queryparams then did observable subscription its return twice.why ? whats the difference.can you pls explain it.

Comment: Actually its difficult to explain without your current implementation. I don't understand where you added another function.

Its better practice to include all of your subscribes directly in the oninit life cycle. then angular will wait for the data to come through the observable you subscribed.Before destroying the component we need to unsubscribe from those observable to avoid memory leakage.

This is like telling angular that-Hey angular i don't need data from here anymore.
Otherwise you can get data multiple times or angular will unnecessarily allocate memory for that observable.